# How to find a cell value within the visible range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of entries to go through very quickly, where one of the columns, Column F, changes fairly often. Since I'm going through each entry individually, I want to highlight the entire row red where the value in Column F changes so that it's easy to see. Here's what I've written so far:

```
Dim visRng As Range, rngTop As Long, rngBot As Long
rngTop = ActiveWindow.visiblerange.Row
rngBot = ActiveWindow.visiblerange.Row + ActiveWindow.visiblerange.Rows.Count - 2
visRng = Worksheets("Work").Range("F" & rngTop, "F" & rngBot)

    For Each Cell In visRng
        If Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(-1).Value _
            And Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
```

I keep getting an error on the row where I define "visRng":

> Runtime Error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

I am fairly new to VBA, and self-taught, so I can't guarantee I'll understand all the jargon. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Set visRng = ` - need to use `Set` when assigning something to an object variable

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you!! I can't believe it was such a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments for explanation.

```
Sub FindAndColor()

    Dim visRng As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range


    '/ Set to range object. Yiu can't simply asign to it.
    '/ This will get rid of Error 91
    '/ Just Use VisibleCells of the usedRange
    Set visRng = Worksheets("Work").UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)

    '/ Loop through the range
    For Each rngCell In visRng.Cells
        If rngCell.Row <> 1 Then
        If rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(-1).Value _
        And rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then    '/ -4142 is the default interior colorindex
            rngCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```